# How can I insert multiple rows into Mysql table with duplicate rows ignored while the row id is returned?

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I'm using java/Mybatis with MySQL in my project. I need to insert multiple rows into a table and I want to ignore those rows which has a dupliate UNIQUE index. Also I want to get to know which rows are ignored. How to do it? it seems to me that `insert ignore into` can not tell me which rows are ignored.

Comment: Why don't you try to filter duplicated record with `JAVA` before data gets inserted? Then `JAVA` codes can help you get the ignored records.

Comment: @Forward there are data in the Database before inserting. These data may be duplicated with data in Java on some `Unique key` fields.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help you out with a solution on how to do that while inserting. But depending on when you need to know the rows that are ignored you could either:

1. Invert you select so that you get all the duplicates before inserting into the new table.
2. Deduct the rows in the sink table from the rows in the source table(s) after the insert.